# Saving a PHP DateTimeInterface into MySQL results in 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Tags: php, mysql

If I have a method that accepts a `\DateTimeInterface`, what is the best way to save that value into a MySQL column?

Right now, the data type of my `date_due` column is a `TIMESTAMP`: When I execute this query, the `date_due` shows as `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

```
public function queueMessage(array $message, \DateTimeInterface $date_due) {

    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `table_name` (message, date_due) values (:message, :date_due)");

    $stmt->execute([
         ':message' => json_encode($message),
        ':date_due' => $date_due->getTimestamp()
    ]);

}
```

Would this be the best practice? Should the `date_due` column be a `DATETIME`, or should I be saving this date in some other manner?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Is there any problem in using either datetime or timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the manual, [DateTime::getTimestamp()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php) returns the Unix timestamp of that date.

```
$date_due->getTimestamp();  // Returns unix timestamp, e.g. '1600349549'
```

To save to your SQL `DATETIME` field, you need to format the date correctly in PHP, then save it:

```
$date_due->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');  // Returns '2020-09-17 06:34:24'
```

---

Alternatively, you can use the Unix timestamp from PHP but then you need to convert it properly in the SQL itself, using [FROM_UNIXTIME()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime).

e.g.

```
INSERT INTO my_table (id, date_due) VALUES (1, FROM_UNIXTIME(1600349549))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So then, if I format the date, your suggestion would be that the SQL field should be `DATETIME` rather than `TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: Generally, if your database field is holding dates that can be changed later, use `DATETIME`. If it's being inserted once and will never change (e.g. a timestamp representing when the record was created) you should use `TIMESTAMP`.